# Can't stash after resolving conflicts

Tags: git

Here's what happened: I pulled some changes and that apparently created a conflict. I resolved the conflict by deleting the conflicting lines in the involved file. I usually don't deal with conflicts, so I am not sure where to go from here. Now I can't stash and pull because

```
file.ext: needs merge
```

What am I supposed to do?

edit: Output of `git status`:

```
On branch some_branch
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/some_branch'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
    modified:   xxx.xy
    modified:   xxx.xy
    modified:   xxx.xy
    modified:   xxx.xy
    modified:   xxx.xy
    modified:   xxx.xy
    modified:   xxx.xy

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)
    both modified:   file_with_conflict.xy

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    some_file
    some_file
    some_file
    some_file
    some_file
    some_file
    some_file
    some_file
    some_file
    some_file
    some_file
    some_file
```

Comment: What do you get for `git status`?

Comment: @AlexanderNied "unmerged paths" for the file in question and a bunch of "untracked files" for the ones I need stashed.

Comment: Nothing about a merge in progress?

Comment: @AlexanderNied I honestly don't know what's going on and I am freaking out because I can break everything if I mess it up. Right now when I `git status` there's a bunch a "modified" files that should never be pushed, they need to be stashed. And then there's "unmerged paths" for the file with the conflict. I resolved the conflict. I only want to commit that conflict solution, but not the rest of the files. When I `git stash` it just keeps saying "needs merge".

Comment: And I don't get why those "modified" fields show up when running `git status` because `git diff` only reports about the one file that had the conflict.

Comment: My hunch is that you are still in a merge resolution state and need to exit it.  @scatter's solution below would probably help you take care of this.  If you are worried about accidentally blowing away your changes, I _believe_ you can make a duplicate of the whole directory-- the git state _should_ be saved along w/ the directory.  W/o seeing your `git status` output it's hard to assist-- you might consider editing your question to add it.

Comment: @AlexanderNied just added the output of `git status` (file and branch names edited of course). All files listed under "modified" or "untracked" should NOT be commited. Only the `file_with_conflict.xy` should. Well, I don't know if it should or not, it's just the one that created the conflict when I pulled.

Comment: Reading that output it seems as though doing `git add file_with_conflict.xy` would mark the file as resolved and allow you to continue? "`(use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)`".  That's similar to what the answer from scatter suggests.  That said, given the situation it sounds like you might want to find someone nearby familiar w/ git to look over your shoulder to help, because the stakes are high and this level of remote debugging is prone to mistakes and misunderstandings...

Comment: @AlexanderNied thank you. It's just that I am used to git locally so now having to deal with it remotely threw me off. Conflicts are a pain. I think I solved it, like I mentioned in the other comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In git, merges are just a type of commit. So to mark conflicts as resolved, you add them to the staged changes after fixing the conflicts.

```
git add path/to/conflicted/file.cpp
```

Once you've resolved all your conflicts in this way, you finish the merge by committing.

```
git commit
```

Alternatively, to cancel the merge, you can abort it to revert your local files to how they were before the conflicts.

```
git merge --abort
```

Comment: Ok I really messed up. I added the file but now when I `git stash` it says there "no local changes to save". I DO NOT want to commit those files. What can I do?

Comment: @dabadaba Are you trying to stash the changes from the merge, without committing the merge itself? I'm not sure if there's a way to do that, but if you explain what you're trying to accomplish I might be able to help.

Comment: I am not sure. This never happened to me, I am not familiar with git at this extent. Please read my comment on the original post.

Comment: @dabadaba You can run `git merge --abort` to return to the state you were in before attempting to merge. The reason `git diff` doesn't show changes is because most of them are staged - you can run `git diff --staged` to see those. Again, it would be the most helpful to tell us what you're trying to accomplish. You mention you need these changes stashed, but why exactly do you need that?

Comment: it says there are no merges to abort. I need to stash those changes because we are running with them temporarily but don't want them commited to the branch.

Comment: @dabadaba You should probably just commit them to a different branch. Stashes are for temporary storage and can't be easily shared/managed. If you aren't currently merging, then you should be able to stash, though? Does `git diff` and/or `git diff --staged` report the changes you wish to stash?

Comment: nevermind, I think I solved it. I ran `git reset`, then stashed, then pulled (not it magically appears that the previous pull applied the changes without conflict), unstashed, and all good